# C++ How can I degrade a class instance in a function call without explicitly casting?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, sdl, operator-keyword

I want to make a Window class that manages a SDL_Window pointer and where accessing the SDL_Window pointer for function calling is as easy and just using the Window class instance and having a conversion operator act as a "getter". Like this:

```
Window win("some name",10,10,100,100,Flags);
SDL_DoSthWithWin(win,10.0f); //SDL_DoSthWithWin uses SDL_Window* but its converted.
```

My current attempt looks (somewhat) like this:

```
class Window{
private:
    //Irrelevant
    SDL_Window *window; //SDL Type for handling Windows. Always a pointer
    static Window *ActiveWindow //Pointer to the active Window.
    //More irrelevant stuff
public:
    static Window& getActive(); //this returns a reference to the active obj
    Window(someParms);
    explicit operator SDL_Window* (){return this->window;}; //This conversion operator should do the trick?
    //More irrelevant stuff really
}
```

However, the outcome is that for some reason it doesnt work without having to explicitly cast like so:

```
SDL_DoSthWithWin((SDL_Window*)win,---);
```

This would be nice if only the entire point of making that conversion operator was to save the letters it would take to write ".getWindow()"

Well how can I (properly) do this so that I dont have to cast.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it works now.... what a dumb mistake.. Please post as answer so I can tick :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you *do* say that the conversion operator is `explicit`. That means you actually have to be *explicit* about that conversion.

I should add that this is usually a bad choice, having an implicit conversion operator like that. Having to be explicit and use a `getWindow` (or similarly named function) to get the `SDL_Window` pointer makes the code easier to understand, read and maintain.